# Firefox rotate3d from -90deg to -180deg bug?

Tags: html, firefox, css, css-transforms

I'm building a 3D content slider jQuery plugin and have a strange behaviour with Firefox where it is rotating from -90deg to -180deg through 270deg in the opposite direction. I am aware that some of this stuff is experimental but I have not been able to find any other documentation regarding this issue, if in fact it is an issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Demo of the issue (view in webkit and FF latest): http://jsbin.com/iwokok/8/ 
The plugin: https://github.com/p-m-p/jquery-box-slider

**EDIT: Bug logged with Mozilla**
You may track the status of the bug report at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769892

Comment: Not sure but may be its a matter of choice of directions to rotate by the browser developers.

Comment: I don't think they would consciously make the decision to rotate a 90 degree increment through 270deg. It also does it from 180deg to 270deg http://jsbin.com/iwokok/9/

Comment: +1 looks like a bug to me, just compared in chrome and FF.

Comment: You could probably hack it to make it do what you want using incremental transforms, but that's beside the point if it's genuinely a bug. If you needed to deliver for a client asap though.. that's different ;)

Comment: It's a personal project so no rush with it, the plugin has other effects that don't require 3D transforms. If I don't get an outcome soon then yeah I'll have to make the faces switch around and always go from 0 to +/-90.

Comment: (and that's a really cool little plugin!)

Answer (score 1):

If you think that you have found a bug with Firefox, then you should file a bug on the Firefox bug tracker:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: The text below is just wrong; I misread the CSS.

You are interpolating between a transform that rotates and then translates and a transform that translates and then rotates.

When the types of the transform functions in the two lists don't match up, per spec both transforms are collapsed into a single transform matrix and the interpolation is performed on the matrices.

In the matrix representation, there is no difference between -180deg and 180deg.  So the interpolation can end up looking like it's going from -90deg to 180deg, depending on the exact interpolation method chosen (last I checked, the 3d transform spec doesn't actually define the exact interpolation method for the matrix).

In general, if you want reproducible results with transform interpolations that don't depend on floating-point errors and various intermediate computations, you want to interpolate between transform lists that have the same functions in the same order.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer, sorry. The same transform functions on the box are always applied in the same order? translate3d -> rotate3d.

Comment: Oh, hmm.  On the box they are, yes.  In that case, I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: Damn, if you don't know Boris who will??!!

Comment: Well, offhand probably David Baron, Matt Woodrow, or Robert O'Callahan.  ;)  If you already have a bugzilla account, I recommend filing a bug on this.  If not, I can do it for you.  Just let me know!

Comment: Thanks Boris, I have signed up and added a bug report (Bug 769892) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769892